# Мне в окно или ко мне в окно?

Tags: орфоэпия

Мне вчера чернокрылая птица влетела в окно

Как правильно сказать в контексте этой строчки:

"Мне в окно" или "Ко мне в окно"

И,если возможно, обоснуйте ответ)

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **Ко мне** вчера чернокрылая птица влетела **в окно**.

**Выбор вариантов "мне в окно" или "ко мне в окно"**

(1) В ту ночь **ко мне в окно** главной башни Тибидохса, где, как ты знаешь, расположена моя алхимическая лаборатория, влетел насквозь мокрый, дрожащий купидончик в красных подтяжках…

(2) Петька подал **мне в окно** парусиновый наматрасник в красную полоску, набитый продуктами.

Выбор предлога КО определяется по глагольному управлению (глагол управляет независимо местоимением и существительным).

Нельзя сказать: птица влетела мне,  он подал ко мне.

Comment: Можно сказать "Птица влетела мне в рот"))))))))

Comment: И такое случается: "Гражданка Петрова зевнула широко, И к ней прямо в рот залетела сорока, Влетела нахально, как в собственный дом, Разинутый рот перепутав с гнездом". Но даже в этом случае, как мне кажется, нужен предлог К/КО.

Comment: Пожалуй, и правда лучше с ним.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: "Ко мне в окно". Глагол залететь требует предложного управления. Предлог к в этом случае показывает направление движения предмета, лица.

К; КО, предлог. 1. Употр. при обозначении предмета или лица как объекта действия, как места, предела, конечного пункта, в сторону которого направлено действие, движение. Скакать к лесу. Плыть к острову.